# Why is there a null in my database when saving a converted mail address?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

Following the code-first approach, I created a model 'User' which contains an attribute mail address and a String 'Name'. When I try and save a record, the mail address is always null.

Since there is no MailAddress SQL data type, I used HasConversion in the fluent API to convert the MailAddress to String, but it's still null in my database.

```
public class User {
  public int ID {get; set; }
  public String Name {get; set; }
  public MailAddress MailAddress {get; set;}
}

public ExampleDbContext : DbContext {
  DbSet<User> Users {get; set; }
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilde) {
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .Property(e => e.MailAddress)
    .HasConversion(
    v => v.ToString(),
    v => new MailAddress(v));
  }
}
```

Edit: The entity adding code Ive been asked to share (or at least an excerpt of the class). That part of the code has, btw, been auto-implemented since I added a scaffold item (option: 'Razor pages using entity framework (CRUD)'):

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel {

  [BindProperty]
  public User User { get; set; }

  public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
  {
      if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          return Page();
      }

      _context.Users.Add(User);
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

      return RedirectToPage("./Index");
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot, guys.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please share your entity adding code.

Comment: @MuhammadHannan I hope the code I added was what you were referring to

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks, I read the article and hope that the edit has improved my question concering its completeness.

Comment: where is `User` defined when you call `.Add`?

Comment: @DanielA.White Ive just added the definition of `User`...

Comment: try debugging at the `.Add` call. is it set right there?

Comment: @DanielA.White At the `.Add` call, `User.MailAddress` contains null..

Comment: then thats your question. why is razor page not binding to that? i dont have an answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested this, but just had a thought to do something like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column("MailAddress")]
    public string MailAddressStr
    {
        get
        {
            return MailAddress?.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            MailAddress = new MailAddress(value);
        }
    }


    [NotMapped]
    public MailAddress MailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

And you would no longer need to override the `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method.

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. This works fine, though it feels kinda sketchy to add an extra property when the value conversion could be centralised in the OnModelCreating mehod. Can you think of why it doesnt work the way I tried? (Don't worry, if neither me nor anybody else can come up with a better solution, I'll accept this answer, of course:) )

Comment: I'm not too sure if I'm honest, if I find anything however I'll let you know as I'm definitely intrigued!